# HTML5 Video element on IPhone has border

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I have been building an app recently and have a loading animation playing at the start (just a mp4 video - for aesthetic purposes). It works great everywhere apart from on Iphone.

The issue is that there is a grey line around some of the video - not the same on every side. If i try to screenshot the page the lines are no longer visible.

I am using an iphone 7 plus and ios safari. To see for yourself see - https:pathfinder-new.herokuapp.com

The goal is for it to be seamless with the white background - example can be seen on desktop at above address.

Cheers, 
Tim

[image]

Answer (score 37):

I’ve been struggling for a few hours and found this as the only way to remove it (tested on Safari, Chrome and Firefox on iOS):

```
video {
    -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

Took inspiration from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ayamflow/b602ab436ac9f05660d9c15190f4fd7b)

Comment: I'm using safari mobile on iOS 14. This trick works, but I cannot figure out the reason. 
As I studied, mask-image uses alpha mask by default so it should be no difference between white and black?

Comment: @sdym I was confused too, there is no apparent reason why it should. That border should not be displayed in first place, so I assume this is some kind of artifact created by Safari on video element rendering in specific conditions.

Comment: Also fixes a similar video bug on Safari 14.1 on Big Sur where those fine borders only appeared when scrolling and disappeared when moving the cursor again.

Comment: Tested on iOS15 beta and this has been the only solution I've found that works. No idea why it works, but thanks!

Comment: Ah thank you so much. I had this bug in Safari desktop. The border was there and disappeared when moving the mouse on the screen. Such a weird bug. This CSS snippet worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I tried that on iOS 12 installed iPad WiFi 2017 on Safari and things were all good. Do you have any chance to video that glitch with another recording device?

Edit: General appearance cleaner `-webkit-appearance: none` may do the trick.

Comment: I have added a photo - hadnt thought to do that hah!

Comment: This made the lines change to be more prominent on the bottom, left and right rather than the top but otherwise no luck :/

Answer (score 0):

I had to go with the approach of a wrapper div and a position absolute one, something like:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <video loop muted autoplay playsinline>
        <source src="./video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="./video.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="./video.ogv" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
    <div class="video-ios-border-fix"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 0;
}

.video-ios-border-fix {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: initial;
    left: -2px;
    top: -2px;
    right: -2px;
    bottom: -2px;
    border: 4px solid #fff;
}

video {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. Same behavior on Safari, Firefox and Chrome on iOS: the border is still rendered on the inner edge of the `.video-ios-border-fix` element. I am on iOS 12.1.

Comment: @ifthenelse Make the border red, much bigger and see how it goes. Set the wrapper div with a much higher z-index, still not working?

Comment: been there, still renders the border in the inner side of the red border.