# How can I remove border from <video> tag?

Tags: html, css

I have a video on my website and everything looks fine on desktop. However, on iPhone (I'm using Chrome) there is a border.  I've tried the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52508598/html5-video-element-on-iphone-has-border/53779216), but none have worked so far (I'm using Bootstrap 4).

My code:

```css
video {
  -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(white, black);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-appearance: none
}

.medio-pago-img-container,
.national-video {
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 col-12 medio-pago-img-container text-center">
  <video src="images/phone-national.mp4" class="national-video" id="nationalVideo" type="video/mp4" width="464" height="500" muted autoplay loop playsinline>Your browser does not support the video tag</video>
</div>
```

I tried taking a screenshot of my iPhone screen but the borders are not shown in the screenshot, so I took a picture of my phone.

[image]

Comment: Im not so sure, but I do not think we have much control over that

Comment: In the css, you can *try* `outline:unset` - especially with Chrome that is sometimes the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The answer given by @cssyphus above worked. I added `outline: unset;` and the border is gone.